# Find the lowest 8 values in an ArrayList and highlight these in a TextView

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which keeps 20 values in, These 20 values are printed out in date order (1 being newest) I want to find the 8 lowest values in this list and then highlight them on the print out.

I have used `Collection.sort()` in other parts of the app to find the 8 lowest values, but this rearranges the order and so I cannot highlight them in date order.

Is there a way to find the 8 lowest values in an `ArrayList` without changing the order of them?

To clarify, the end goal is to display all 20 values on a page in the order they were input. So there is no numberical order to these. i.e they could be `6,3,9,8,9,9,10,4` etc. When displayed I want the lowest 8 values to be highlighted so for the above numbers if I wanted lowest 3 highlighted it would be

```
"6"
"3"
9
"8"
9
9
10
"4"
```

with the numbers in quotes being highlighted but left in the same position on the print out.

Currently in my `display()` I use `s1.setText(masterlist.get(0)` etc so I need to be able to find the 8 lowest and then for these 8 use `s1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)`

Comment: You could copy the ArrayList.

Comment: Sort a copy of the original ArrayList. Then you can get the information on the 8 lowest values from there while printing the original list.

Comment: `originalList.stream().sorted().limit(8).collect(toList())`.

Comment: If they're already "in date order", can't you just use `originalList.subList(...)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I want to find the 8 lowest values. so if for example values range from 2 - 9 but not in ascending order, i want to find the lowest 8 values and then highlight these but keep them in date order.... so the 2nd, 8th, 10th etc might be the lowest and highlighted.

Comment: @RalfRenz but I want to print the original list and highlight on that list the 8 lowest values.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comment of @andi-turner this could be your method:

```
void printHighlighted(List<String> originalList){
  Set<String> eightLowest = originalList.stream().sorted().limit(8).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  // print logic
  originalList.forEach(s-> {
       if(eightLowest.contains(s)){
           // replace by your actual print code
           System.out.println("BOLD: " + s);
       } else {
           // replace by your actual print code
           System.out.println(s);
       }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: You don't need to collect them to a list if you're just going to invoke `forEach`.

Comment: Note the `forEach` is iterating the original list, to keep the order of the original 20 values. Maybe I understand something wrong here

Comment: I dont think this will work as I need to use setBackgroundColor on the TextView for a specific TextView. ie if score1 is one of the lowest 8 I need to use s1.setBackgroundColor()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the lowest values in a set first (Suppose values are integer)

```
Set<Integer> lowestValues = list.stream().sorted().limit(8).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then filter the list if contains in the list then you get the order in the orginal list.

```
List<Integer> res = list.stream()
                        .filter(e -> lowestValues.contains(e))
                        .limit(8)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why collect to a set, though? You've got the 8 smallest values from `list.stream().sorted().limit(8)`; just collect that to a list directly.

Comment: @AndyTurner Actually for getting the original order of item on the list.

Comment: @Rono Thanks. I have used this so now have the 8 lowest values, but I now need to find which these values are in the original list and highlight them on the page.

Comment: @JamesSmith In 2nd part doing the job to get the lowest values in order.

Comment: Read here in your spare times https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers